# Moq setup: Passing a class to a moq and checking if a property is not null?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I have this POCO class:

```
public class Item
{
     public int ID {get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string Flag { get; set; }
```

And I have this repository:

```
public class Repo : IRepo
{

     int CreateNewItem(Item myItem)   // defined in the IRepo interface
     {
           if (myItem.Flag == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("The Flag property cannot be null!!);

           // other implementation here 

           primary key = cmdSql.Reader.GetInt(0);

           return primary_key;
     }
}
```

Now in the database, the Flag **cannot be null**, and therefore need to have a value in the property and hence why I have an IF statement to check the property. I want to set up a Moq to test to see if the Flag property is not null, and if so, throw an error. Otherwise, it will return a value, like 1 for example.

How do I set that up for Moq?

Comment: For the record: I assume this is C# - but you probably want to make that explicit, for example by adding that tag. The language might very much affect your option space.

Comment: uhm, yeah, it is C#. I thought that would be pretty obvious with the automatic properties in the POCO class I gave in my example

Comment: Thing is: of course you shouldnt over-tag. But having the specific language tag *also* helps in attracting viewers. More viewers increase your chances of receiving helpful input.

Answer (score 0):

Your class 'Repo' is not unit testable now as you haven't injected the dependency for 'cmdSql'. Once you inject type od 'cmdsql' then mock it either with a mocking framework or manual mocking. A unit test shouldn't have any kind of dependency (like database, files, class dependency etc.) and all dependencies should be mocked.

If my understanding is correct what you want achieve is to set a flag, which is a property of your entity. You don't need to mock the entity as there isn't any dependency to resolve (Buy you should mock 'cmdsql' as I have mentioned before). In your test method you can directly instantiate the entity and set the flag to null. To test the exception you can decorate your test method with 'ExpectedException' attribute like below,

```
[TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void GivenCreateNewItemWhenIPassNullFlagThenArgumentNullException()
    {
       //Arrange

      //Act

      //Assert
    }
```

If you want to read about dependencies please read https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/even-config-file-dependency-unit-test-which-you-mock-viswanathan , which I have written last week.

Comment: Using `ExpectedException` attribute can lead in situations where your test fails for "wrong" reason, for example if some of the configuration code throw this exception. At this moment all testing frameworks have methods to assert that correct exception was thrown even with expected message

Comment: Well, yes, it is required that I unit test the repository. That's  the whole point. I'm required to test out the functionality of the repository to make sure that all is working correctly. And as the project grows, the unit test makes sure that nothing gets broken. If it does, at least we narrow down where and why it broke.